# htaccess to provide security

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What code could I put in an htaccess file that would prevent anyone from being able to access sensitive information (i.e. passwords etc) in another file. Pretend this other file is named "passwords.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (but haven't tested):

```
<File passwords.php>
    Deny from all
</File>
```

Comment: thanks, but you think that would still give my program access to the information inside passwords.php?

Comment: @Michael: htaccess only controls access via HTTP. It cannot stop programs (or users) running on the server from accessing the file system directly. For that you need to set the file system permissions properly (so that PHP process cannot see the files at all).

Comment: @Michael: Oh yes. I assumed you meant to stop people from the web side from accessing the file. Thilo is entirely correct; .htaccess has nothing to do with access by programs/users on the server itself.

Comment: Actually, on second reading of Michael's comment, I think he means it as a good thing. As in, he wants to stop web-side users from accessing the file but *does* want to give local programs access to it. I guess that's why it's called `passwords.php` -- the PHP program can access the passwords but nobody coming in through Apache can. So this would be the appropriate technique in that case.